# ERROR: "Can't save to disk (check for space, write permission, or name)" while creating TIN in memory

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, tin, memory

I get the following error while creating TIN in memory
: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Can't save to disk (check for space, write permission, or name).
Failed to execute (CreateTin).

I don't have any issue with writing any feature class in memory, I wonder why it doesn't work for TIN.

```
TIN = arcpy.CreateTin_3d("in_memory/TIN", Coordinate_System, "XS_lyr P001 hardline FID", "DELAUNAY")
```

When I remove the "in_memory/" and just save it on local drive it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the **[Fundamentals of Creating TIN Surfaces](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006000000010000000)** help page, **TINs are file-based**.

If you want to store a **Triangulated Irregular Network** (**TIN**)-based surface in a geodatabase (and think of an in_memory workspace as being much like a file geodatabase), then you should use a **[Terrain Dataset](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0311/terrain-datasets.html)**.